# base 64 decoding of image string gives invalid image django 1.6

Tags: ajax, django-templates, django-views, base64

I seem to be running into a lot of issues with my django/ python development.

I am trying to submit a user-uploaded image to the django server (which I am able to do). The image is in a HTML5 canvas element which I convert to a jpeg using `canvas.toDataURL()` function. I am able to view the canvas element converted to jpeg and I am also able to display the URL in an alert message on the HTML page through `javascript`.

Once I am sure that my image has been converted to a string I send the image data via `AJAX` to my `django views.py`. This is the code for the following actions that I do.

In my HTML file,

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="480" width="400" data-girar="0"></canvas>
<img src="/static/images/uploadedPhoto/uploadedPic.jpg" id="image" height="100%"/><br>
<input type="button" id="AdjustDone" value="Done"/>
```

In my javascript, I have my ajax call

```
$('#AdjustDone').on('click', function() {             

         var userAdjustedImage= document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg');            
         window.open(userAdjustedImage, 'new_window', 'width=400,height=480');  // opens the correct image
         alert(userAdjustedImage)  // alerts the string which the image has been converted to

         $.ajax({

            type:"POST",

            cache:false,

            url: "/displayAdjustedImage/{{frame.slug}}/", 


            data: {
                'userAdjustedImage': userAdjustedImage,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                },

            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',

            success: function() {
                     alert("Success");
                 },
            error: function() {
                    alert("Oh no! There seems to have been some problem with the picture you uploaded");
                  },
          });
          //return false;


    });
```

which returns a success.

So now the image which has been converted to a string has been sent to the django view. In my `views.py` , I have to decode it.

```
from base64 import b64decode

def displayAdjustedImage(request, frameslug):


    print "frame displayAdjustedImage"
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
        userAdjustedImage = request.POST.get("userAdjustedImage")
        print "fmypic", userAdjustedImage
        userAdjustedImage_decoded=base64.b64decode(userAdjustedImage)
        #print "userAdjustedImage_decoded",userAdjustedImage_decoded
        filename_uploadedImage = "UserAdjustedPic.jpg"            
        path=''
        f = open('%s/%s' % (MEDIA_ROOT1, str(path) + str(filename_uploadedImage)), 'wb')                       
        f.write(userAdjustedImage_decoded)
        print "AJAX"
    else:
        print "Hello not AJAX"
    return render_to_response('dumdata.html')
```

When  I print the  `userAdjustedImage` it gives me the string that I had sent which is something like this.

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQ..
```

When I print the  `userAdjustedImage_decoded` version I get not the RGB  values that I expect. Instead I get something like this.

```
 1]ä02Bc♂│τ♥Ñi┼♥░►▓üü£π¡ZIΩ╠σ[ùC╬¢└╔!1ä∙O|U;┐j▬Mσ█!h█╨g§ΩMnë≈ù≥ñî.Γ6î{èN◄!b,╧↨ô└Ü
ò─ñ6Γ:φ½►ⁿ.Üa╞Q╜┼{      è♦m┼↨≡Ñ‼B╜▬ù│E}d≥½oâVΣy╙0▄=kb█ß·┘─♀*î↨⌐☻╗⌡{e╔♠¢÷ÿ├α6►Äh÷
╥d◄]<αÿ╬↨o╥⌐╟µ`⌐ê◄ΩE☼r╜í╬╢Äó|(%♣]ÅJDpA²*⌠ë:╔≥á♥┌úû≥Γ)Ç1±L₧v╞}Ö§└⌂╥ú╣é\f▌A↔Ωy/→Lⁿ
ü⌂
ìnB#s┌ä╡╕ÆôeIDêÇ┐╩EC 3D~l╒û)s¥∩┼U¥V◄än+[ª¼jöè↨VAJ¥╪Γ░uk9\`7§╡{+9↑læY╖w'g1‼⌠¼Σæ╝*
4rwp▓─PîƒZ┬₧☻Ç
```

Why is the image not being decoded properly. I get an `INVALID IMAGE` when I go to the path that I specified for the file write. What is happening here. Stuck here for a long time. Please help. Would be grateful to you :)

Comment: strip away `data:image/jpeg;base64,` before calling `base64.b64decode`. That is header in data uri scheme, not part of base64 coding. You want to decode just `/9j/4AAQSK...`.

Comment: I tried doing that. What I get is a thoroughly distorted image which is in no way similar to the original image. Is it possible that there is some incompatibility in the encoding at the client side and the decoding in the Django views.?

Comment: Hi @huocp -- After some string manipulations, this finally worked. I guess it was a problem with both the import and the Will you put it down as an answer. I will b happy to accept it.:)

Comment: glad it works out for you :-) Never mind, it's too trivial to be an answer.